# I want to give my HDD execute permission, to be able to set it as Steam install location

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, chmod

It says "New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions." when i try to select my HDD. How can i give exec permission to my HDD?

The steps were like that:
1 Installed Steam for Linux from the site.
2 Tried to change the install location from my SSD to HDD.
3 Wasnt able to do it and Steam said i should select a folder that is on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions.

(I guess thats the most i can explain, since i just did those to meet the error)

Comment: Please update your question with information about what you have done when you get this error (commands, steps, etc.). My guess is that you are selecting a directory that your user does not have write permissions to, select a directory in your home directory.

Comment: I did not do anything actually. "My guess is that you are selecting a directory that your user does not have write permissions to" ? Oh, reallly? I just want to install my games to my HDD not 32 GB SDD. If you know how to do the trick with chmod and etc. you can help me.

Comment: Is it necessary for me to always install stuff on SSD, while using Linux. I mean i dont think 32 GB will be enough tho. Why cannot i just use my HDD for files like game files?

Comment: "i should select a folder that is on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions." That excludes NTFS ;-)

Comment: Yeah thats just my dumbness to forget i formatted it. Problem solved so is all fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remount the HDD with special mount parameters or change the entries in your /etc/fstab.
This [article](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864974467574115543?l=german) refers exactly to your problem.
One of their fixes is:

> If you are using the directive "user(s)" in your /etc/fstab, you must
>   specify "exec" afterwards. "user(s)" implies "noexec", that's a
>   security feature. The directives are processed in order, specifying
>   "exec" after "user(s)" solves this problem.

Comment: Gave me an error like this : The file "/etc/fstab" is read-only.

Comment: Perfect, glad to help.